# Minecraft seeds multiplayer vs singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I went to my multiplayer server and typed /seed:

```
2200642393142709666
```

I created a singleplayer world with this seed and went to the same location in both worlds. They are different.

Why? How can I generate my multiplayer map in singleplayer mode?

Comment: Side note before I suggest stuff: I don't operate a server of my own. Are you sure you used the same version to generate each world?

Comment: and does the world-type parameter match?

Comment: How old is your multiplayer world? The way terrain is generated changes from version to version, so if that terrain was generated before an upgrade that could explain why they're different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in the world generation algorithm between single player and multiplayer. If you use the same seed and same world type in the same version, you will get the same map.

The most likely problem is that the multiplayer server was made in a different version. The generation algorithm can change from version to version and is always updated when new biomes are added. If the server was made before December 10th 2013, it would have been running an older version of Minecraft.

To generate the multiplayer map, you would need to use the version it was made in.